# Find values of $t$ so that this matrix is positive definite

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I will start from this point:

$\det{\left(B-\lambda I\right)}=0\Longleftrightarrow\begin{vmatrix}t-\lambda&3&1\\3&t-\lambda&0\\1&0&t-\lambda\end{vmatrix}=0$

Now we will compute the determinant:
$(t-\lambda)^3-9(t-\lambda)-(t-\lambda)=-\lambda^3+t^3-3\lambda t^2+3\lambda^2t-10t+10\lambda=$

$t^3 -  (-10\lambda + 3 \lambda^2 + \lambda^3) + 
  (-10t + 3 \lambda^2t)$

Now i have a problem, how can i simplify that equations so that i will find the values of t so that matrix B is positive definite?

Comment: You need to solve the characteristic equation for $\lambda$ and discuss the signs of the roots as a function of $t$. Hint: solve for $t-\lambda$ and notice $t-\lambda=0$ is a solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a slightly simpler way of solving this problem. A matrix is positive definite if the signs of all the sub-determinants of the matrix are positive. This means we need

$$\begin{vmatrix}t\end{vmatrix}=t>0$$
$$\begin{vmatrix}t&3\\3&t\end{vmatrix}=t^2-3>0$$
$$\begin{vmatrix}t&3&1\\3&t&0\\1&0&t\end{vmatrix}=t^3-10t>0$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: This means $t>0, t^2−3>0,t^3-10t>0$.
So the final solution is : $-\sqrt{10} < t < 0$  and  $t > \sqrt{10}$ Am I right?

Comment: You can drop the $-\sqrt{10}<t<0$ part since we know that $t>0$.

Answer (score 2):

Always look closely before expanding products: when you find
$$
(t-\lambda)^3-9(t-\lambda)-(t-\lambda)=
$$
you should collect $t-\lambda$, getting
$$
(t-\lambda)\bigl((t-\lambda)^2-9-1\bigr)
$$
So one of the eigenvalues is $\lambda=t$, the others are the solutions of
$$
(t-\lambda)^2=10
$$
that is,
$$
t-\lambda=\pm\sqrt{10}
$$
that is,
$$
\lambda=t+\sqrt{10}\qquad\text{or}\qquad\lambda=t-\sqrt{10}
$$

Comment: Sorry, but from $\lambda=t+\sqrt{10}$ can i conclude directly that $t>\sqrt{10}$?

Comment: @BioShock Yes: the eigenvalues are $t-\sqrt{10}$, $t$ and $t+\sqrt{10}$, so the least one is $t-\sqrt{10}$.